# How to send createdDt, updatedDat values in the angular form without showing them in template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have a create message form and sending a few formcontrols and I need to send the createdDt and updated it as a hidden value where it shouldn't show in the angular template. I want to set the current date and time for createdDt and updatedDt

```
ngOnInit() : void {
    this.addMessageForm : this.formBuilder.group({
    'messageTitle' : new FormControl(''),
    'messageDec' : new FormControl(''),
    'messageSentBy' : new FormControl(''),
    'createdDt' : ?
    'updateDt'  : ?
    })
    
    createMessage(this.addMessageForm.value).subscribe(data=> {
     console.log("Message Created Successfully")
    } ,err => {
     console.log("Message Failed to Create")
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `createdDt` and `updateDt` should be also `FormControl`s, just don't add them in the form, and if you need to update those properties, do it as usual using `setValue`, `patchValue`, it doesn't matter since those 2 are not attached to your `form`

```js
this.addMessageForm : this.formBuilder.group({
    'messageTitle' : new FormControl(''),
    'messageDec' : new FormControl(''),
    'messageSentBy' : new FormControl(''),
    'createdDt' : new FormControl('')
    'updateDt'  : new FormControl('')
})
```

```html
<!-- no createDt and updateDt -->
<form [formGroup]="addMessageForm">
  <input formControlName="messageTitle" />
  <input formControlName="messageDec" />
  <input formControlName="messageSentBy" />
</form>
```